# Minimal time to boil squid

Tags: food-safety, squid

I know that squid is often cooked for one-two minutes to make it still tender. However is one minute enough to kill possible parasites? What is the minimal time of boiling for squid? If that's important then lets say it's already cut into small rings. It's frozen but I am worried that freezing might be incorrect or not enough.

Comment: Is your squid fresh, or frozen?

Comment: @Onyz It's frozen. But people who freeze it in Russia may not be trust-worthy. Maybe it's frozen in a wrong way.

Comment: Thanks. Could you edit your question to include that information, as well as the caveat that while it is frozen, you would prefer an answer that covers 'unsafe freezing' as a possibility?

Comment: @Onyz it's done

Comment: Thank you. :) I hope my answer is helpful to you. Have a great day, and I hope your squid is delicious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As is usually the case with food safety, it is not purely the time something is cooking, but the temperature. Most recipes, even for fresh squid, call for a very short boil in water. If, out of an abundance of caution, you wanted to make absolutely sure that your squid is cooked safely, the [CDC](https://www.cdc.gov/parasites/anisakiasis/faqs.html) mandates that the internal temperature of seafood should reach 145° F [~63° C].

The most cautious method available is measuring the internal temperature of your cooked squid to ensure that it is up to temperature. That is the most surefire, consistent way to test food safety.

However, this is *probably* overkill and is especially overkill if your squid are already frozen.

Answer (score 2):

If your squid is pre-frozen you don't have to worry; these parasites die when frozen. And most of the squid you buy will be pre-frozen.